# Data check between source and the target as per transformation rule

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have two tables one is source and the other is target.

I need to check if the data is properly transformed according to the transformation logic or not.

Here is the source table:EmpIn

```
empid year  quarter  amount
5     2007    q1       100
5     2007    q2       200
5     2007    q3       300
5     2007    q3       100
5     2007    q4       50
5     2007    q4       100
5     2007    q4       150
```

Target table after the transformation:EmpOut

```
empid   year   quarter   amount    sequence number
 5      2007     q1       100          0
 5      2007     q2       200          0
 5      2007     q3       300          0
 5      2007     q3       400          1
 5      2007     q4       50           0
 5      2007     q4       150          1
 5      2007     q4       300          2
```

Transformation logic is : If there is another entry of amount with respect to same quarter and the same year
                          the amount will be addded to the previous amount and the sequence number will be increased by 1 in the target.

for example in the source table in 2007 q3 we have two amounts the first one is 300 it will go as is to the target with sequence number
of zero
the next entry is a addition to the previous amount which is 400 and the sequence number is incresed by 1.
the same transformation is happening to the fourth quarter also

We(I) need to validate if the data is properly transformed according to this logic to the target table or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Creating dataset*/
create table #tmp1 (empid int, year int,  quarter  varchar(25), amount int)
Insert into #tmp1 
select 5,2007,'q1',100 union
select 5,2007,'q2',200 union
select 5,2007,'q3',300 union
select 5,2007,'q3',100 union
select 5,2007,'q4',50  union
select 5,2007,'q4',100 union
select 5,2007,'q4',150 


/*Intermediate dataset*/
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by empid,quarter order by amount) as ID
    ,* 
Into 
    #tmp2
from 
    #tmp1 order by 2,3,4

/*Desired output dataset*/
select 
     a.empid
    ,a.year
    ,a.quarter
    ,sum(b.amount)
    , a.ID-1 as [sequence number]
from #tmp2 a , #tmp2 b
where 
    a.empid=b.empid 
and 
    a.year=b.year 
and 
    a.quarter=b.quarter 
and 
    a.ID>=b.ID
group by  
    a.ID,
    a.empid,
    a.year,
    a.quarter,
    a.amount
Order By 2,3,4,1
```

Comment: check to validate your target result with the output from above query

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't just validate the transformation algorithm?

- Add a field "original_amount" in the destination table
- Loop over all rows with sequence no > 0
- Subtract the amount from the former row (sequence no - 1) from the current row's amount and update the new field with the result
- Update the field with the amount of the same row for sequence no = 0
- Compare the two table's amount and amount_original

Like so.